# In an EE file field is it possible to upload multiple files without the use of a plugin?

Tags: expressionengine

I've got a file field that I would like to be able to upload multiple images from. Is there a way to do this in EE without the aid of any add-on?

Comment: Please post these questions to [Expression Engine Answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/).  Short answer though is nope.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm fairly new to EE and wasn't aware of the dedicated forum. I kind of suspected that this is not a core feature.. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload multiple file using FTP. Upload your files to your upload directory folder using FTP. After you can synchronize file from File Upload Preferences

Content > Files > File Upload Preferences

Here you can synchronize.

Comment: I was looking more for a way to select multiple files on one channel entry form field.

Answer (score 0):

No, not natively. The reason being is the native File Field can only hold a single file. So no amount of trickery is going to allow it to hold multiple files.

To get around this limitation you'll need to use a field type such as [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) coupled with [Matrix Multi Upload](http://github.com/pixelandtonic/matrix_multi_upload). For a complete package that allows multi-selection uploads from the fronted, the [Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) plugin may be of help.

The Grid field type will allow you to hold multiple files, [but the limitation is you'll only be able to upload 1 file at a time to each cell](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17682/multi-file-upload-into-grid).